# Django: site loads static files but django admin does not

Tags: django-admin, django-staticfiles

I have been noticing a weird problem on my site. I have managed to make my regular site load all the static content by defining STATIC_URL and STATIC_ROOT directives. However, when I go to mysite.com/admin, the admin site does not load any css at all.

Comment: Have you run collectstatic? `python manage.py collectstatic`.

Comment: I have done it numerous times and it does not work.